# Tridion search not working after changing MTSUser

Tags: 2011, cme, search-engine

We currently have a Tridion CM server where search is working fine in a production environment.

We have cloned this server to create a new machine in a test environment, and changed the MTS user. Everything is working fine, except the solr search.
We have changed the MTSuser to a different user in the tridion configuration snap-in, but the error we receive is : "user is not in required role".

There must be some small configuration setting we're missing, but we can't find what the problem is.
Anyone has an idea/pointer where to look ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've seen this before ... during the installation the group `sdlsearchusers` is created.

At this point, the `MTSUser` (in the appropriate domain e.g DOMAIN\MTSUSER) is added to the group. If you've cloned the machine - did you change the domain or the `MTSUser` name? if so then you probably need to re-add this into the `sdlsearchusers` group

Comment: that was indeed one of the causes. We found that we did indeed have to add the new MTSuser to this group, but as the machine name changed (we duplicated the server), we also had to change the group name in the solr jetty config (solr-jetty\conf\webdefault.xml). This configuration file contains the sdlsearchusers group setting

Comment: Note that in SDL Tridion 2013 this is now %TRIDION_HOME%\solr-tomcat\conf\web.xml