# (403) Forbidden Error using Tridion core service and SearchQueryData

Tags: core-service

I am trying to get list of components within a publication based on given Schema Uri. The code is:

```
   SearchQueryData query = new SearchQueryData()
   {
          BasedOnSchemas = new BasedOnSchemaData[] { new BasedOnSchemaData() { Schema = new LinkToSchemaData() { IdRef = SchemaTcmUri } } },
          SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData() { IdRef = PublicationUri },
          ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component }
   };
   try
   {
          XElement xResults = client.GetSearchResultsXml(query);
   }
   catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException commProblem)
   {
          Console.WriteLine("There was a communication problem. " + commProblem.Message + commProblem.StackTrace);
          Console.Read();
   }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
There was a communication problem. Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService.GetSearchResultsXml(SearchQueryData filter)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient.GetSearchResultsXml(SearchQueryData filter)
   at ExtractUpdateComponetData.ExtractComponentInfo.ComponentInfo() in \App_Code\ExtractComponentInfo.cs:line 50
```

Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

CM Version:SDL Tridion 2011 SP 1

Warning in Event Viewer:

```
Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. 
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 854 
User: server\tridion_admin 
StackTrace Information Details: System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.ProcessResponse(HttpWebRequest,Boolean,Boolean,String&) 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Post(String,String,String&) 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Query(String,Int32,Nullable`1,String&) 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResultsFromSolr(SearchQueryData,Int32,Nullable`1) 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResultsFromSolr(SearchQueryData,Int32,Nullable`1) 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResults(SearchQueryData,Int32) 
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.ComWrapper.SearchQueryEngineFacade.GetSearchResults(Int32,Int32) 
SearchBLST.GetListData SearchBLST.GetSearchResults 
at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.SearchQuery.GetListResults(Int32 startRowIndex, Int32 maxRows) 
at Tridion.ContentManager.Query.GetListResults() 
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetSearchResultsXml(SearchQueryData filter) 
at SyncInvokeGetSearchResultsXml(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Cm version?
Search was changed from release to release.

Comment: Also look to EventViewer...there will be additional message.

Comment: Does search work from the CME?

Comment: Searching a tcmuri works fine in the CME Search but searching a string throws the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Unable to get the list of search results. 
Error occured while processing the request: User not in required role.

Where should I add the user??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have seen something similar before. Can you check this Question and Answer ?
[Tridion search not working after changing MTSUser](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/tridion-search-not-working-after-changing-mtsuser)

The problem lies in a 403 error thrown by the solr web application.