# Tridion 2013 SP1 Search Access Denied

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, search

We recently upgrade our DB for Tridion 2013 SP1. Before the DB switch search was working fine but now after the switch we can no longer perform a search. We get the following error.

> Unable to index item: tcm:13-1588. Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 - Error report
>
> ## HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** Access to the requested resource has been denied
>
> **description** Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/7.0.39

I am no sure exactly where to look to fix this. I got this from the D:\Tridion\solr-tomcat\logs files

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [24/Sep/2014:16:10:20 -0500] "POST /tridion/update HTTP/1.1" 401 951
>   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - **OUR-ACCOUNT** [24/Sep/2014:16:10:21 -0500] "POST /tridion/update HTTP/1.1" 403 1057

I am not sure if th account (our-account) from above is really the issue or not. And if it is what rights does it need and where is this account configured out with Tridion search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had some access-related problems with search before as well, and it turned out to be the user not being added to a windows group named "sdlsearchusers".
(see [Tridion search not working after changing MTSUser](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/tridion-search-not-working-after-changing-mtsuser)).

Can you check if the user "our-account" is added to this group ?

Comment: Close Harald so I will give you credit :) as it got us going in the right direction. The root of the issue was that we changed the name of the box and the sdlsearchusers was a local group (instead of domain group) so the web.xml role-name did not match anymore.  

`<security-role>  
        <role-name>WAS WRONG\SDLSearchUsers</role-name>  
</security-role>`

Comment: I also had this issue after a rename with 2013 SP1. The file in question than need to be changed was  %TRIDION_HOME%\solr-tomcat\conf\web.xml